# Getting pictures to display from an XML feed

Tags: php, xml, rss, feed

I have tried numerous attempts, but can't seem to get the images from this feed into mine. I'm just looking for the thumbnails to be present on my feed too. Can anyone help?

```
<?php    

$XMLpath = 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/technology/rss.xml';


$xml = simplexml_load_file($XMLpath);


//Title of feed

echo '<h3>'.$xml->channel->title.'</h3>';
echo '<h3>'.$xml->channel->description.'</h3>';
echo '<p>'.$xml->channel->date.'</p>';
echo '<hr>';

// Feed content

 foreach( $xml->channel->item as $item ) {

    //var_dump($item);

echo '<h3>'.$item->title.'</h3>';
echo '<p>'.$item->description.'</p>';
echo '<p><a href="'.$item->link.'">Read more..</a> ('.$item-                   

>pubDate.') </p>';
echo '<hr>';

}
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$XMLpath = 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/technology/rss.xml';


$xml = simplexml_load_file($XMLpath);
$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);

//Title of feed

echo '<h3>'.$xml->channel->title.'</h3>';
echo '<h3>'.$xml->channel->description.'</h3>';
echo '<p>'.$xml->channel->date.'</p>';
echo '<hr>';

// Feed content

 foreach( $xml->channel->item as $item ) {

    //var_dump($item);

echo '<h3>'.$item->title.'</h3>';
$thumbnail=$item->children($ns["media"]);
if(!empty($thumbnail)){
  $thumbnail_attrs=$thumbnail->thumbnail[1]->attributes();
  $image=$thumbnail_attrs["url"];
  echo "<img src='$image'></img>";
}
echo '<p>'.$item->description.'</p>';
echo '<p><a href="'.$item->link.'">Read more..</a> ('.$item->pubDate.') </p>';
echo '<hr>';

}
?>
```

Comment: Brilliant - could you just explain briefly what you did, so i can get my head around it?

Comment: Declare the namespace for the media tag (line 7).

Then grab its children (line 23).

In this case, thumbnail seems to be the only object in there, but you could imagine lots of different media types, so the media namespace allows you to avoid naming conflicts in the document.  

Then since not every item has a thumbnail, check to make sure it's not empty (line 24), and then print it out if it exists.  

Here's a good tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/parsing-xml-with-simplexml/